# PCIE USB 3.0 Controller not working

Tags: drivers, 13.10, usb, pcie, lspci

I am running Ubuntu 13.10 and just got a Sharkoon USB 3.0 PCI-E x1 Controller but can't get it to work.

I tried `lspci -v` and can see the controller. What now?

```
$ lspci -v

    02:00.0 USB controller: Renesas Technology Corp. uPD720202 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 02) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
        Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 16
        Memory at fe9fe000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
```

Edit:
lsusb with a usb stick connected.
The Western Digital Technologies Passport is connected to my onboard USB 2.0 and the MLK Trust Deskset is wireless my Mouse and Keyboard.

```
 $ lsusb


Bus 002 Device 002: ID 1058:0704 Western Digital Technologies, Inc. Passport External HDD
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device MLK Trust Deskset001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 017c:145f MLK Trust Deskset
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Edit: I checked dmesg.

```
$ dmesg | grep xhci
[    0.586087] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: xHCI Host Controller
[    0.586093] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 9
[   24.714828] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: can't setup
[   24.714832] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: USB bus 9 deregistered
[   24.714879] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: init 0000:02:00.0 fail, -110
[   24.714883] xhci_hcd: probe of 0000:02:00.0 failed with error -110
```

Comment: `lsusb` and `lsusb` with something connected to it?

Comment: I am not at home so I can only show you lsusb with something connected to it.

Comment: So I did it with nothing connected and it's the same.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.techpowerup.com/forums/threads/ver-3-0-2-5-firmware-update-to-nec-renesas-usb-3-0-controller-unloading-fix.130099/page-3

There was a post on this page from "Crone" about his WD Passport not being recognized either.

This may be a hardware issue, Check for  a newer firmware from the manufacturer.

Answer (score -1):

Renesas Technology Corp. uPD720202 is not going to work on linux.

Comment: it's working perfectly on Ubuntu 18.04 with 5.4 kernel on this PC: https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=c945332cad . With a kernel > 5.8 you will have do some dynamic firmware loading stuff.

Comment: Hm, that's something on the motherboard isn't it? I have a PEXUSB3S44V with four D720202 chips and it is definitely not working.

Comment: Can you share a hw-probe?